# Configure Sass output

Tags: sass

I'm new to Sass want to be able to check the output, and would like it to be in the style of my handcrafted CSS, specifically:

- A newline before the closing }
- A tab instead of spaces before each
  declaration

I tried sass `--watch file.scss:file.css --style expanded &` but it didn't do anything, and my understanding is that won't change the spaces to tabs.

What's the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Did the file recompile?  If you were running it with a different output style before, then change to a different output style without some sort of code change in between, the file won't be recompiled.

Comment: No, it didn't recompile. How do I do that?

Comment: Just modify the Sass file and save it.  Adding a space or newline should be good enough that it will recompile.

Comment: Understand, but it's still not working.

Comment: All production CSS should be minified.

Comment: Absolutely, and I'm talking about development. However if I can't change it to :expanded I don't fancy my chances with :compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`--watch file.scss:file.css --style=expanded`

The difference is the `=`

When I did it with the equals sign, it worked.